# Why is gradle keeps downloading itself again and again with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've downloaded Android Studio and using it for like a year, things get annoying when you repeatedly see gradle is being downloaded.

> - I have a built-in gradle distribution somewhere inside 'Android Studio.app'.
> - When I need to import a eclipse ADT project, it's downloading another gradle dist to
>     ~/.gradle/wrapper/gradle-2.2.1-all/[WTFstring]/...
> - When I go to the project dir, and execute ./gradlew, again, it starts to download gradle.
> - And when I add ~/.gradle/wrapper/gradle-2.2.1-all/[WTFstring]/gradle-2.2.1/bin to
>     path, then execute 'gradle tasks' in the project dir, again, it's
>     again downloading gradle!!

Not sure if you have experienced something similar? This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Enable offline mode in `Android Studio` to disable checking for updates everytime.

> Go to Settings>Compiler>Gradle>Offline mode.

If this is enabled the gradle will be told not to connect to internet and check for updates.

[image]